# Commands not showing up

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am developping a discord bot and I have created some slash commands I wanted to test on a specific server.
But when I tried to see my slash commands, they weren't showing.

So I invited the bot on another server of mine and took a look : the commands are showing and working. Does anyone have any idea why my commmands won't show up on one specific server ?
I've tried reinviting the bot with full permissions but never got the commands to show up.
Thanks by advance for helping !

Comment: There's not a lot of info here to determine what is the exact cause of this. Did you enable the `applications.commands` scope when inviting it to your guild? Did you try restarting your discord client? Are your commands set per-guild?